# Asserting object count in a JSON response using groovy script

Tags: groovy

I have a question on how to assert the element_count equals to the number of objects from response.

The link to the API is https://api.nasa.gov/neo/rest/v1/feed?start_date=2019-05-10&end_date=2019-05-16&api_key=*******

I tried using the below code but did not have any luck trying to count the objects from the JSON response using grrovy script.

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
def ResponseMessage = messageExchange.response.responseContent
def response = new JsonSlurper().parseText(ResponseMessage)
def elementCount = response.element_count
def idCount = response.count { it.equals('neo_reference_id') }
```

I was trying to count the number of neo_reference_id which should equal element_count. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def url =  new URL('https://api.nasa.gov/neo/rest/v1/feed?start_date=2019-05-10&end_date=2019-05-16&api_key=***')
def response = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse( url )
def neo_references = response.near_earth_objects.collectMany{date,objects-> objects.collect{it.neo_reference_id} }
println neo_references
println neo_references.size()
assert response.element_count == neo_references.size()
```